# Program that prints one word per line

Tags: python

Need to create a program that prints one word per line, but only if that word is less than 4 character. I have this so far

The input will be a list such as ['Not','very','good','at','python']

```
string = input("Enter word list:")

txt = string.split()

for words in txt:

     print(words)
```

When the input is a list, it prints it in one line, but if the input is just text, for example

Enter word list: Not very good at python

then it'll print every word on its own single line.

Not sure how to implement a 4 character only print and not sure how to get the list to print its elements on its own lines

Answer (score 1):

well, check the length of the word.

```
string = input('Enter word list:\n')
txt = string.split()

for word in txt:
    if len(word) < 4:
        print('{0}'.format(word))
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: You can just do `print(word)` and you don't need the `else` :)

Comment: true, just wanted to be explicit

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in function `len()` to count the length of each word. I have also included a simple parsing if statement to detect if your input is a list.

```
string = raw_input('Enter word list: ')

if string[0] == "[" and string[-1] == "]": # simple method to parse
    print(string)
else:
    txt = string.split()

    for words in txt:
       if len(words) <= 4:
           print(words)
```

Comment: this works when the input is Stop Desktop but not when the input is a list such as ['stop','desktop']

Comment: @jason00 So if the input is ` ['stop','desktop']`, you want to print the entire line i.e. output is ` ['stop','desktop']` as well? Can you please add more detail to your question, for that case?

Comment: is input is ['stop','desktop', 'here'] outt put should be stop on line one and here on lines there without brackets or quotes

Comment: @jason00 If input is `['stop','desktop', 'here']`, output should be what? Provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

When you input['Not','very','good','at','python'],there has ‘，’. But when you input "Not very good at python", there not has ','.

Answer (score 0):

Is the input you are providing literally ['Not','very','good','at','python']?
If so that's your problem.  The input is being seen as a literal string, not a list.  Calling split on that input will produce a single item list of your input "list", as there are no white spaces in that string to split on.
I'm also seeing nothing in your bit of code that determines word length for printing but perhaps that was just omitted.

Comment: I'm trying to add something that determined word length, not sure how to implement it

Comment: So for that you simply just want to do 

if len(words) < 4:
   print(words)